# I am using 000webhost to deploy laravel but I am getting error

Tags: laravel, web-hosting

I am trying to host on 000webhost but I keep getting this error. I have tried generating new autoload cleared the cache.

Edit: After clearing the route cache and config cache zip the project. It then works

```
> Warning:
> require(/storage/ssd2/942/16963942/accidentmanagement/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /storage/ssd2/942/16963942/accidentmanagement/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
> on line 69 What should I do Warning:
> require(/storage/ssd2/942/16963942/accidentmanagement/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /storage/ssd2/942/16963942/accidentmanagement/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
> on line 69
> 
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/storage/ssd2/942/16963942/accidentmanagement/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
> /storage/ssd2/942/16963942/accidentmanagement/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
> on line 69
```

Comment: Did you refer this link [Deploying your Laravel Project to 000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-on-000webhost/127323)

Comment: Yes, Thank you I already hosted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open `laravel project`

1st: Step

```
laravelProject\bootstrap\cache\config.php
```

rename the `config` file

```
laravelProject\bootstrap\cache\config_old.php
```

2nd: Step

```
laravelProject\bootstrap\cache\routes-v7.php
```

rename the `routes` file

```
laravelProject\bootstrap\cache\routes-v7_old.php
```

then run your project its run 100%.

Answer (score 2):

run `composer dump-autoload` before you make zip and upload project files to hosting and please make sure you include `vendor` folder in the upload.

Comment: I tried everything still getting this error